# How to calculate wavenumber domain coordinates from a 2d FFT

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I have a 2d Array of complex numbers that represent a potential field measured along a plane in real space. Lets say that the array is 128 cells by 128 cells and the the total area of the plane is 500m x 500m. Each cell in this array represents a point in the spatial domain with co-ordinates given in x and y.

When I use the 2d FFT from scipy.fftpack on this 2d array I get the same information represented in the wave domain. How do I calculate the wave domain co-ordinates kx and ky for the points the output array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is some code to fully demonstrate the problem and the solution I was able to find.

```
from numpy import linspace , arange , reshape ,zeros
from scipy.fftpack import fft2 , fftfreq
from cmath import pi

# create some arbitrary data
some_data = arange(0.0 , 16384.0 , dtype = complex)

# reshape it to be a 128x128 2d grid
some_data_grid = reshape(some_data , (128 , 128) )

# assign some real spatial co-ordinates to the grid points   
# first define the edge values
x_min = -250.0
x_max = 250.0
y_min = -250.0
y_max = 250

# then create some empty 2d arrays to hold the individual cell values
x_array = zeros( (128,128) , dtype = float )
y_array = zeros( (128,128) , dtype = float )

# now fill the arrays with the associated values
for row , y_value in enumerate(linspace (y_min , y_max , num = 128) ):

  for column , x_value in enumerate(linspace (x_min , x_max , num = 128) ):

    x_array[row][column] = x_value
    y_array[row][column] = y_value

# now for any row,column pair the x_array and y_array hold the spatial domain
# co-ordinates of the associated point in some_data_grid

# now use the fft to transform the data to the wavenumber domain
some_data_wavedomain = fft2(some_data_grid)

# now we can use fftfreq to give us a base for the wavenumber co-ords
# this returns [0.0 , 1.0 , 2.0 , ... , 62.0 , 63.0 , -64.0 , -63.0 , ... , -2.0 , -1.0 ]
n_value = fftfreq( 128 , (1.0 / 128.0 ) )

# now we can initialize some arrays to hold the wavenumber co-ordinates of each cell
kx_array = zeros( (128,128) , dtype = float )
ky_array = zeros( (128,128) , dtype = float )

# before we can calculate the wavenumbers we need to know the total length of the spatial
# domain data in x and y. This assumes that the spatial domain units are metres and
# will result in wavenumber domain units of radians / metre.
x_length = x_max - x_min
y_length = y_max - y_min

# now the loops to calculate the wavenumbers
for row in xrange(128):

  for column in xrange(128):

    kx_array[row][column] = ( 2.0 * pi * n_value[column] ) / x_length
    ky_array[row][column] = ( 2.0 * pi * n_value[row] ) / y_length

# now for any row,column pair kx_array , and ky_array will hold the wavedomain coordinates
# of the correspoing point in some_data_wavedomain
```

I know this is likely not the most efficient way of doing this, but hopefully it is easy to understand. I hope this helps someone avoid a little frustration.

Comment: It was such a bliss when I discovered the `fftfreq()` function!

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, it seems if I use the FFT function, that DC ends up at element zero, also in your case the spacing between frequencies is 1/500m.  Thus the following (not very concise) snippet will get your frequency axis:

```
meter = 1.0
L     = 500.0 * meter
N     = 128

dF    = 1.0 / L
freqs = arange(0, N/L, dF)  # array of spatial frequencies.
```

Naturally these frequencies are in cycles-per-meter, not radians-per-meter.  If I wanted kx and ky to be arrays of spatial frequencies in rads/meter I would just say

```
 kx = 2*pi*freqs
 ky = 2*pi*freqs
```

(Assuming I have imported in things like arange, and pi already).

**edit**

Stu makes a good point about frequencies above the Nyquist, which you might prefer to think of as negative (I usually do, but not in the code).  You can always do:

```
freqs[freqs > 0.5*N/(2*L)] -= N/L
```

But if you really want negative frequencies you might also want to play with fftshift, as well -- another can of worms.

Comment: In my answer above the wavenumbers for both kx and ky at [0][0] are 0 indicating the DC mean of the area. Your freqs don't show the switch to negative frequencies at N/2.

Comment: I don't think we disagree here.  The DC component of the output array is at [0][0].   The main difference between as seems to be that I use 1-d frequency axes and you produce 2-d meshgrids.   If I understand your code correctly.

Comment: I calculate the values as an array when it could be done with a 1d axis assuming that the input grid is equal in size in x and y, which is not always true for my data. But the frequency output of the fft increases from 0 to 2*pi*(n/2 -1) over the range of [0:n/2 -1] but then continues from -2*pi*(n/2) to -0 over the range of [n/2:n]

Comment: You need to consider the negative frequencies as real data if your input spatial domain data is represented as complex numbers, like in the case of electromagnetic fields.

Comment: You are quite right, if the input code is not square you have to calculate separate kx and ky values (and though you don't need grids, they can be handy).  As for negative vs. positive frequencies, the whole frequency axis is module the sample rate, so this is a matter of taste/convenience/convention.  I prefer to keep my axes continuous, so no -ive frquenies unless I have also done an fftshift; but that's just me.  I guess what you mean by EM fields is that we are using DFTs to approximate continuous Fourier integrals (where -iv frequencies really are absolute).  Yup.

Comment: The transforms I am applying to the data in the wavenumber domain depend on correctly calculating kx and ky. This includes them being negative when they should be negative. I understand that when you are trying to represent the data in a way that makes sense to people it is easier to avoid negative frequencies, but then the equations don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found subroutine in FORTRAN code below, and try to implemented it as matlab function. Please give me a comment whether my translation is right. 
Here we Go, This is FORTRAN subroutine :

```
subroutine kvalue(i,j,nx,ny,dkx,dky,kx,ky)
  c Subroutine KVALUE finds the wavenumber coordinates of one
  c element of a rectangular grid from subroutine FOURN.
  c
  c Input parameters:
  c i - index in the ky direction,
  c j - index in the kx direction.
  c nx - dimension of grid in ky direction (a power of two).
  c ny - dimension of grid in kx direction (a power of two).
  c dkx - sample interval in the kx direction,
  c dky - sample interval in the ky direction,
  c
  c Output parameters:
  c kx - the wavenumber coordinate in the kx direction,
  c ky - the wavenumber coordinate in the ky direction,
  c
  real kx,ky
  nyqx=nx/2+l
  nyqy=ny/2+l
  if(j.le.nyqx)then
      kx=(j-l)*dkx
  else
      kx=(j-nx-l)*dkx
  end if
  if(i.le.nyqy)then
          ky=(i-l)*dky
  else
          ky=(i-ny-l)*dky
  end if
  return
  end
```

I translate to MATLAB function :

```
function [kx,ky]=kvalue(gz,nx,ny,dkx,dky)
nyq_x=nx/2+1;
nyq_y=ny/2+1;
for i=1:length(gz)
    for j=1:length(gz)
        if j <= nyq_x
            kx(j)=(j-1)*dkx;
        else
            kx(j)=(j-nx-1)*dkx;
        end
        if i <= nyq_y
            ky(i)=(i-1)*dky;
        else
            ky(i)=(i-ny-1)*dky;
        end
    end
end
```

Thank you.